# Make SSRS Multiple Values parameters act like a "AND"

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Working with SSRS, i have a parameter that allow multiple values. The problem is that it act like an OR and not like a AND.

Exmple :

Suppose i have datas like :

> 1, A, Monday
>
> 2, A, Tuesday
>
> 3, B, Monday
>
> 4, B, Friday

And these data are grouped by lettre. Now if my multiple value parameter is set on `Monday, Tuesday`

Both A and B will be shown, because B has a value equal to at least one parameter, in this case, `monday`. But it's totaly useless in my case cause i want people to be able to search for people that are available on monday AND tuesday.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm assuming that the data block you listed above is the data you're querying from the db.  Can you describe what your parameter data list looks like?

Comment: well the parameter @Day is a multiple value and otions are all the day between monday and friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parameter cannot validate multiple rows at one time for a single criteria.  You should restructure your data so that you have a column for each day of the week and then mark whether that person is available or not in each column.  Then you would have to create a parameter for each day of the week and you would then be checking to see

```
WHERE Monday = 'YES' AND Tuesday = 'YES'
```

Comment: Well yeah, i was thinking of something shorter but i suppose this is the only way